# The influence of NA data when using describe

Tags: python, describe

I have a dataframe and I made a copy of it. On the copy I replaced all NA by -99999 and the original remained the same. When I used the same describe() function on both of them, I get very different results. I'd be very happy is someone could explain what happens on the backstage of this coding. 
Moreover, The -99999 didn't show up when I plotted the graph, which makes me think that there were no NA to begin with. I am confused.

Here is the code:

```
df1 = df.copy()

df1['price'].fillna(-99999, inplace = True)    # replace NA data with -99999

df['price'].describe()

df1['price'].describe()
```

And the respective results are:

```
df['price'].describe()

Out[126]: 

count     16869745.0

unique        7305.0

top             40.0

freq         26098.0

Name: price, dtype: float64
```

And:

```
df1['price'].describe()

Out[127]: 

count    1.686974e+07

mean     3.191416e+01

std      1.165290e+01

min      1.000000e+00

25%      1.999000e+01

50%      3.529000e+01

75%      4.077000e+01

max      5.411000e+01

Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Strange. It looks like it is treating `df` like a non-numeric column...

Comment: This may be related to the following [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13118), which I believe has been fixed. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: I am using 0.20.1 for pandas and 3.6 for python. I think this is the newest version (?)